# ABCpdf - convert pdf stream to tif stream

Tags: pdf, stream, tiff, abcpdf

My web page has a document viewer (canvas) where I will bind a multi-page `tif` file stream.

There is a functionality to delete pages from the file, I am using the `ABCpdf` library to convert the `tif` file stream to a `pdf` stream and delete a particular page. But I don't see any way to convert back the `pdf` stream to a `tif` stream.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `GetData()` method, called as `GetData("foo.tif")`. The filename passes is ignored except that its extension is checked to see what format to use. The return value is an array of Byte.

https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2F5-abcpdf%2Fxrendering%2F1-methods%2Fgetdata.htm